# win32api module does not give the current language code when used in a while loop

Tags: winapi, windows-10, python-3.5, keyboard-layout

I am trying to get the current language code using python and win32api module. I am on Windows 10 (64-bit) and my python version is 3.5.2. My problem is when I simply call `win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName()` it gives me the current language code correctly. However, when I put the function in a while loop and change the keyboard layout while the script is running, I get the same language code. In other words it only shows the language code prior to running the script and does not update as I change the keyboard layout in real time. Any help on this is appreciated.

You can find a MWE here:

```
import win32api
import time
msg = 'The current language code is: %s'
while True:
    current_language_code = win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName()
    print(msg % current_language_code)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

## UPDATE:

I just figured out that win32api works in a per-process manner, i.e. when I run my script `win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName()` gives me the keyboard layout for the current procress which does not change (unless I explicitly call `win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout()` myself in the script). That explains why the output of the while loop does not update (change) as I change the global keyboard layout (accessible in the tray bar).

So is there anyway to get the global keyboard layout and detect its changes in python via win32api?

Comment: Are you sure you're not switching to an input method that's provided by a Text Service instead of through a keyboard layout? What are you switching between?

Comment: @andlabs : yes iam sure! switching between Persian and English ( US ) ...